# Permisission with mplayer

Tags: permissions, video, mplayer

I am trying to use mplayer to directly play video into the framebuffer.
Currently I cannot get the audio and video to play on the same run level.

The audio devices will only connect if I am in user level, while the video device is refused.

for example I can run:

```
  mplayer -ao alsa -vo fbdev2 test.mp4
```

which will play the audio but refuse the video connection

```
 can't open /dev/fb0: Permission Denied
```

If I use `sudo mplayer -ao  alsa -vo fbdev2 test.mp4` then the video plays but there is no audio.

```
 [AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection Refused
 [AO_ALSA] Playback open error: Connection Refused
 Failed to initialize audio driver 'alsa'
 Could not open/initialize audio device -> no sound
 Audio: no sound
```

How do I get both audio and video to play together? Both of them work separately at different run levels.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer, loggedin with root reside virtual consoles(i.e. Ctrl+Alt+N), then start pulseaudio daemon and play video:**

```
 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start
 mplayer -vo fbdev2 test.mp4
```

**[Important]** tried with `/usr/bin/pulseaudio --system` is not required here. And you **MUST reside root(not sudo or even su) AND virtual consoles to perform all the step** including start daemon and play video. **No effect** if you try `su` and start daemon inside X Session's virtual terminal.

**Long answer, how i figure out:**

First step, open new terminal with new virtual console. The reason behind is because X session most likely will not work with framebuffer.

Now i need to know is it limited to mplayer or not. So i tried with play command to play basic music, e.g. built-in kde sounds, `play /usr/share/sounds/KDE-Im-Cant-Connect.ogg` with sudo on new virtual console:

```
$ sudo play /usr/share/sounds/KDE-Im-Cant-Connect.ogg
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

play FAIL formats: can't open output file `default': snd_pcm_open error: Connection refused
$
```

It's not limited to mplayer or complex song.

So now we have to dive into difference between **got sound** and **no sound**. let's try strace on normal user on X session(got sound), (file name su1.log is misleading here, nothing to do with su):

> strace -o /tmp/su1.log -v -s 1000000 play
>   /usr/share/sounds/KDE-Im-Cant-Connect.ogg

and  virtual console(no sound):

> strace -o /tmp/su2.log -v -s 1000000 play
>   /usr/share/sounds/KDE-Im-Cant-Connect.ogg

vi /tmp/su2.log, navigate the end:

```
connect(8, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/run/user/0/pulse/native"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(8)                                = 0
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 8
fcntl(8, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
setsockopt(8, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PRIORITY, [6], 4) = 0
fcntl(8, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(8, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
connect(8, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/pulse/native"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(8)                                = 0
write(5, "x", 1)                        = 1
write(2, "ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) ", 37) = 37
write(2, "PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused\n", 50) = 50
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
futex(0x135a8e0, FUTEX_UNLOCK_PI_PRIVATE, 0) = 0
sendto(7, "W", 1, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = -1 ENOTSOCK (Socket operation on non-socket)
write(7, "W", 1)                        = 1
futex(0x135a8e0, FUTEX_UNLOCK_PI_PRIVATE, 0) = 0
futex(0x7f34065089d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 7956, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
munmap(0x7f3406509000, 67112960)        = 0
unlink("/dev/shm/pulse-shm-3719764676") = 0
close(6)                                = 0
close(7)                                = 0
close(5)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
write(2, "play FAIL formats: ", 19)     = 19
write(2, "can't open output file `default': snd_pcm_open error: Connection refused", 72) = 72
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
```

And also kdiff3 to compare both logs's "open(":

```
$ grep 'open(' /tmp/su1.log > /tmp/su1_open.log 
$ grep 'open(' /tmp/su2.log > /tmp/su2_open.log
$ kdiff3 /tmp/su1_open.log /tmp/su2_open.log 
$
```

[image]

It's slightly different for **/run/user/0/pulse**, now i realized uid 1000(normal user) and 0(root) stuff, in which "/run/user/1000/pulse" and "run/user/0/pulse" only request when play with uid 1000 and 0 respectively:

```
$ grep 'run/user/0/pulse' /tmp/su1.log
$ grep 'run/user/1000/pulse' /tmp/su2.log
$ grep 'run/user/1000/pulse' /tmp/su1.log
recvmsg(5, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\10\2\0\21\0\0\0\37\0\0\0\0\0\0\0B\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0{34959d136592433aad171659a5cd523f}unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 100
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/run/user/1000/pulse/native"}, 110) = 0
recvmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\10\2\0\21\0\0\0\37\0\0\0\0\0\0\0B\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0{34959d136592433aad171659a5cd523f}unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 100
connect(6, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/run/user/1000/pulse/native"}, 110) = 0
$ grep 'run/user/0/pulse' /tmp/su2.log
mkdir("/run/user/0/pulse", 0700)        = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
open("/run/user/0/pulse", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
lstat("/run/user/0/pulse", {st_dev=makedev(0, 41), st_ino=86867, st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_nlink=2, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=0, st_size=40, st_atime=2015/07/22-01:44:45, st_mtime=2015/07/22-01:44:45, st_ctime=2015/07/22-01:47:59}) = 0
lstat("/run/user/0/pulse", {st_dev=makedev(0, 41), st_ino=86867, st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_nlink=2, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=0, st_size=40, st_atime=2015/07/22-01:44:45, st_mtime=2015/07/22-01:44:45, st_ctime=2015/07/22-01:47:59}) = 0
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/run/user/0/pulse/native"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mkdir("/run/user/0/pulse", 0700)        = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
open("/run/user/0/pulse", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC) = 8
lstat("/run/user/0/pulse", {st_dev=makedev(0, 41), st_ino=86867, st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_nlink=2, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=0, st_size=40, st_atime=2015/07/22-01:44:45, st_mtime=2015/07/22-01:44:45, st_ctime=2015/07/22-01:47:59}) = 0
lstat("/run/user/0/pulse", {st_dev=makedev(0, 41), st_ino=86867, st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_nlink=2, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=0, st_size=40, st_atime=2015/07/22-01:44:45, st_mtime=2015/07/22-01:44:45, st_ctime=2015/07/22-01:47:59}) = 0
connect(8, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/run/user/0/pulse/native"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
$
```

"No such file or directory" only when /run/user/0/pulse, let's check(with root):

```
# l /run/user/0/pulse/
total 0
84490 drwx------. 4 root root 80 Jul 22 01:44 ..
86867 drwx------. 2 root root 40 Jul 22 01:44 .
#
# l /run/user/1000/pulse/
total 4.0K
29328 -rw-------.  1 xiaobai xiaobai   5 Jul 22 00:58 pid
30544 srwxrwxrwx.  1 xiaobai xiaobai   0 Jul 22 00:58 native
31058 drwx------.  2 xiaobai xiaobai  80 Jul 22 00:58 .
27430 drwx------. 14 xiaobai xiaobai 280 Jul 22 01:06 ..
# l /run/user/1000/pulse/native 
30544 srwxrwxrwx. 1 xiaobai xiaobai 0 Jul 22 00:58 /run/user/1000/pulse/native
# file /run/user/1000/pulse/native     
/run/user/1000/pulse/native: socket
# file /run/user/1000/pulse/pid 
/run/user/1000/pulse/pid: ASCII text
# cat /run/user/1000/pulse/pid     
2205
#
```

At this point i know **pid 2205** is running and supposed to be exist with uid 0 to make it works.

I google and found **pulseaudio --check**:

```
# pulseaudio --check
```

Tried with arg verbose, gotcha! daemon is running as **pid 2205**, proved what I've observed above:

```
# pulseaudio --check -v
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon running as PID 2205
#
```

So now i confident that pulse audio can make it works. Check pid 2205 to find out how it was triggered:

```
# ps aux|grep 2205
xiaobai   2205  0.0  0.2 565980 11080 ?        S<l  00:58   0:01 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start
root      8747  0.0  0.0 113008  2300 pts/2    S+   01:58   0:00 grep --color=auto 2205
#
```

So let's tried `/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start`:

```
#  /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified).
N: [pulseaudio] main.c: User-configured server at {34959d136592433aad171659a5cd523f}unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native, which appears to be local. Probing deeper.
```

What now, new pulse directory is appear under uid 0 with new pid:

```
# l /run/user/0/
total 0
17794 drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 80 Jul 22 01:44 ..
85629 drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 80 Jul 22 01:44 systemd
84490 drwx------. 4 root root 80 Jul 22 01:44 .
86867 drwx------. 2 root root 80 Jul 22 02:02 pulse
# cat /run/user/0/pulse/pid 
9731
#
```

And finally the sound is works. Try it yourself now with `mplayer -vo fbdev2 test.mp4`

[Note] `su` might work in some weird circumstance. E.g. X session 11 -> Ctrl+Alt+2 -> login with uid 1000 -> su - root -> `/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start` and mplayer -vo fbdev2 works fine. Then Ctrl+Alt+3 -> login with root -> `/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start` and mplayer works together -> go back Ctrl+Alt+2 -> mplayer on virtual console 2 no longer works.